# Need help copy/pasting in Excel VBA from one workbook to another

Tags: excel, copy, range, paste

I need to find out how to write some basic code that will take each cell's value (which will be an ID number) from a selected range, then match it to a cell in a master workbook, copy said cell's entire row, then insert it into the original document in place of the ID number. Here's the kicker: certain ID numbers may match with several items, and all items that have that number must be inserted back into the document. Here's an example:

```
Master Document              Workbook
A   B   C   D                A   B   C   D
1   a   ab  ac               2
2   b   bc  bd               3
2   b   be  bf               
3   c   cd  de
```

I would select the cells containing 2 and 3 in the Workbook, which after running the code would give me this:

```
Workbook
A   B   C   D
2   b   bc  bd
2   b   be  bf               
3   c   cd  de
```

Here's what I have going on so far but it's a total mess. The only thing it's managed to successfully do is store the selected range in the Workbook I want to paste to. It won't compile past that because I don't understand much of the syntax in VBA:

```
Sub NewTest()
Dim rng As Range
Dim FirstRow As Range
Dim CurrentCol As String
Dim FirstRowVal As Integer
Dim CurrentColVal As Variant
Dim rngOffset As Range

CurrentCol = "Blah"
Set FirstRow = Application.InputBox("Select the row containing your first raw material", Type:=8)
FirstRowVal = FirstRow.Row

Set rng = (Application.InputBox("Select the cells containing your IC numbers", "Obtain Materials", Type:=8))
Set rngOffset = rng.Offset(0, FirstRowVal)
CurrentColVal = rng.Column

Call CopyPaste

End Sub

Sub CopyPaste()
Dim Blah As Range
Set x = Workbooks.Open("Workbook Path")
Workbooks.Open("Workbook Path").Activate


Set y = Workbooks.Open("Master Path")
Workbooks.Open("Master Path").Activate

With x
For Each Cell In rng
x.Find(rng.Cell.Value).Select
If Selection.Offset(0, -1) = Selection Then
Selection.EntireRow.Copy
Selection = Selection.Offset(0, -1)
Else
Selection.EntireRow.Copy
Blah = Selection
End If
Workbooks.Open("Workbook Path").Activate
Sheets("Formula Sheet").Select
Blah.Insert (rng.Cell)
End

Sheets("sheetname").Cells.Select
Range("A1").PasteSpecial
'Sheets("sheetname").PasteSpecial
.Close
End With

With x
.Close
End With
End Sub
```

Would very much appreciate anyone who could help point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll bite, you can use the output array to populate any range on any worksheet.

[image]

```
Sub FindAndMatch()

    Dim arrMatchFrom() As Variant, arrMatchTo() As Variant, arrOutput() As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, counter As Integer

    counter = 0

    arrMatchFrom = Range("A2:D6")
    arrMatchTo = Range("G2:G3")

    For i = LBound(arrMatchTo, 1) To UBound(arrMatchTo, 1)
        For j = LBound(arrMatchFrom, 1) To UBound(arrMatchFrom, 1)
            If arrMatchTo(i, 1) = arrMatchFrom(j, 1) Then
                counter = counter + 1
                ReDim Preserve arrOutput(4, counter)
                arrOutput(1, counter) = arrMatchTo(i, 1)
                arrOutput(2, counter) = arrMatchFrom(j, 2)
                arrOutput(3, counter) = arrMatchFrom(j, 3)
                arrOutput(4, counter) = arrMatchFrom(j, 4)

            End If
        Next
    Next

    For i = 1 To counter
        For j = 1 To 4
            Debug.Print arrOutput(j, i)
            Cells(9 + i, j) = arrOutput(j, i)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```